# Firebase auth using refresh token in mobile app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello Flutter community,

I've been working with Firebase Auth in my Flutter app and have encountered an issue related to Firebase ID tokens, which are short-lived and last for only an hour. To provide a smoother user experience, I want to implement a refresh token logic so that users won't have to log out after being away from the app for more than an hour.

After researching, I discovered that the Firebase SDK doesn't directly support refresh tokens for native platforms like Android, iOS, and macOS, which makes it challenging to find a straightforward solution.

Considering the popularity of Firebase Auth in mobile apps, I'm wondering how others have dealt with this refresh token limitation. Are there any workarounds or best practices that you can suggest?

Any insights, code snippets, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

I'm currently using the `firebase_auth` library in Flutter, but I haven't found a clear path forward for handling refresh tokens.

Best regards,
Ron

Comment: The client SDKs automatically refresh the ID tokens as needed.  You don't have to do anything.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson! Do i need to do something to refresh it? Because I’m getting error from the API the token expired, so I’m calling logout… do I need to do something else instead?

Comment: If you're having a specific problem, you should show the [complete minimal reproducible code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) that doesn't work the way you expect and provide instructions on what you do to reproduce it.